# Is it supposed to take a while for styles to update on Wordpress localhost?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm programming using Notepad ++ and using a localhost to build out wordpress themes. I've noticed that I save the stylesheet, then I go to refresh the wordpress page and it doesn't show an effect. I check the source code, and it's still using the old style sheet.

Then a couple of minutes later, it uses the new one. I've seen people have stylesheets update automatically, I'd like to know if there's anything special I need to be doing to make this so?

Comment: Potentially a caching issue. Try ctrl + f5 (on windows) to refresh your browser.

Comment: Yup that worked thanks. Am I going to have to do that all the time?

Comment: @logos_164 the old version is cached so yes, every time you make modifications to styles, you will have to refresh the browser

Comment: Sorry, got the refresh the browser part, but I mean go in and clear browsing data. That's what I had to do to eat it to work

Comment: Just disable your browsers cache. Chrome has a neat feature where you can choose to disable cache while devtools are open